Linkedin-api-,Advertising API {id} does not work
I have an approved  Advertising API inside my Linkedin App so the "r_basicprofile", "r_1st_connections_size" scopes are granted.
I am looking for the number of the connections of the user which based on the document could be get via /rest/connections/{id} endpoint.
When I get the access token ( put it in the header of the get request) then I want to reach https://api.linkedin.com/rest/connections/{id}{I think id of the inkedin user and can be retrieve via r_basicprofile} I get the following error:
{"message":"Key parameter value 'XXXXXX' is invalid","status":400}

Where I assumed the id can get via r_basicprofile is "XXXXXX" which it looks it is not right. Anyone knows what I need to replace for {id}?

According to the LinkedIn documentation, you don't need to specify a user id in the call. Instead, just use an access token that was granted by the user whose connections you want to query (e.g. for the user with id 'XXXXXX').
You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api

Thank you but if I use https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&projection=(paging) or  I  use https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&start=0&count=50 then I get
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections",
"status": 403
}
In both of cases I use access token on the header. One thing is that I do not have access to r_compliance that might be needed to get the total connections. How could I have access to it? I also need to add that I add LinkedIn-Version: 202401 in the header of the get API end points.

My bad, I sent you the documentation for the Compliance API, for which you need a different permission (r_1st_connections).
You are however using the Advertising API and it seems that you are already having the necessary permissions.
Have you tried using the urn of your user instead, as specified here?
If you get a BadRequest error, try to encode your request as you can see here
